# What is the difference between ros &ros electric?

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,i want to know What is the difference between ros &ros electric ?..and which one i should to install and use for my project on roboearth stack ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45700/what-is-the-difference-between-ros-&ros-electric-?/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is the name of the operating system (like windows or ubuntu). Electric is the specific distro (like XP and vista or precise pangolin 12.04 and oneiric ocelot 11.10).

ROS Fuerte is the current distro as of 10.12.12, and it's recommended that you use that.

You should check out the [introduction to ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) and the [ROS distribution page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Distributions) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-10-12**:
So as not to confuse someone who is new to all this, remember that ROS is not an "operating system" in the common sense of the term.  It is not its own linux distribution, for example.  It still must be run on an operating system, like Ubuntu/Windows.